# Can a Google Datastore Entity with a composite index be created via the DatastoreV1 interface run from a DataFlow pipeline?

Tags: indexing, pipeline, apache-beam, composite, datastore

I have a Dataflow pipeline that creates an Entity in Google Datastore. I can then search for that entity within the pipeline using a Query, but only if I don't include an Operator.GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL Filter on a timestamp property.

When I include that more complex query, I get the error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: FileInjectionRecord
  properties:
  - name: FilePath
  - name: LastModifiedDate
, code=FAILED_PRECONDITION
```

It seems fairly clear that I need to take the recommended index in the error message and add it to an index.yaml file, but all the documentation that I have seen so far about this talks about including the index.yaml file in your WAR file, which I don't have in this case.

Is it possible to define a composite index somewhere in a Dataflow pipeline or do I need to set this up as a one off outside of the pipeline?